# Superclass mismatch for class RegistrationController - Overriding Devise Controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I am trying to override my devise registration controller, with no luck.

I finally got the routes working, but now I'm getting an `superclass mismatch for class` error.

Heres my setup:

Registration Controller (app/controllers/users/registrations_controller.rb)

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController

  def sign_up_params
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.sanitize(:sign_up)
    params.require(:user).permit(:email, :password, profile_attributes: [:username])
  end

  def new
    super
  end

  def create

  end

  def update
    super
  end

end
```

Routes

```
root 'welcome#index'

devise_for :users, :controllers => {:registrations => "users/registrations"}
```

Views

--`edit.html.erb` && `new.html.erb` exist in the folder (app/views/users/registrations)

User Model (just in case)

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  has_one :profile
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :profile

  def profile
    super || build_profile
  end

end
```

Any idea why this error is appearing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your controller is underneath the users directory but does not have a Users module (it is not in the Users namespace, you might say). Either change the controller to this:

```
module Users
  class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  ...
  end
end
```

Or move your controller up a directory

app/controllers/registrations_controller.rb

Answer (score 3):

Define your  `RegistrationsController` as below

```
class Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  ...
end
```

By defining the controller as suggested above, you don't need to define the module explicitly.
You get the error because you have placed the `RegistrationsController` inside `users` folder.
So, rails expects that `RegistrationsController` is a class belonging to `Users` module.

Comment: This is what i expected to work, but for some odd reason it gives the following error : `Unable to autoload constant Users::RegistrationsController, expected [...]/app/controllers/users/registrations_controller.rb to define it`

Comment: That error comes when you define the module incorrectly. Most probably you tried with `User::RegistrationsController` instead of `Users::RegistrationsController`. Note pluralized Users.